# How to transfer data to another thread and make helgrind know it?

Tags: c++, race-condition

I have two threads:

- Data preparation thread
- Data processing thread

How should I transfer data from one thread to second?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- queue
- two semaphores, one set to maximum number of items the can be held by the queue and one set to zero and it will indicate how many elements are there
- one mutex to prevent more threads accessing the queue at the same time

For more information google "producer-consumer" problem.